# C++/templates: Can I selectively disable a function of a class at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates

I need to write 2 constructors for a quaternion class that basically contains nothing but 4 elements of a numerical type `T`. I have 2 constructors in conflict at compile time (see below). Is it possible to tell the compiler to ignore the constructor from an iterator if I want to call the constructor that takes 4 ints (my attempt commented out - it seems the compiler sees my attempt as all or nothing to instantiate the whole class). The (clang) compiler complaint is "ambiguous conversion", and it lists these 2 constructors when trying to do `Quaternion<float> x(1);`

With my commented out attempt, clang tells me:

```
error: no type named 'value_type' in 'std::__1::iterator_traits<float>'
      typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>::value>::type>
```

The code:

```
template <typename T>
class Quaternion {
  public:
   template<typename T1>
   Quaternion(T1 a = 0, T1 b = 0, T1 c = 0, T1 d = 0)
   : _a(static_cast<T>(a)),
     _b(static_cast<T>(b)),
     _c(static_cast<T>(c)),
     _d(static_cast<T>(d)) { }

   template <typename It>
   //typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>::value>::type>
   Quaternion(It it)
   : _a(static_cast<T>(++it)),
     _b(static_cast<T>(++it)),
     _c(static_cast<T>(++it)),
     _d(static_cast<T>(++it))
   {}

  private:
    T _a, _b, _c, _d;
};
```

Comment: What about that `std::enable_if` attempt?

Comment: Added note - thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: And that happens with `Quaternion<float>` instantiation?

Comment: I got it - I'm using "T" in the commented out line when I should use "It" :-( I'm going to remove this question.

Comment: By the way, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628974/why-cant-the-compiler-deduce-the-template-type-from-default-arguments), why you should have `template<typename T1 = T>` for the first overload, if you want to default-construct it.

Comment: `++it` should be `it++`? Otherwise you skip the first item..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a custom trait `is_iterator`:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterator {
   static bool const value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_iterator<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>::value>::type> {
   static bool const value = true;
};
```

And SFINAE out your constructors with a defaulted template argument in the following way:

```
template<typename T1, typename = typename std::enable_if<!is_iterator<T1>::value>::type>
Quaternion(T1 a = 0, T1 b = 0, T1 c = 0, T1 d = 0)
:_a(static_cast<T>(a)),
 _b(static_cast<T>(b)),
 _c(static_cast<T>(c)),
 _d(static_cast<T>(d)) 
 {}

template <typename It, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_iterator<It>::value>::type>
Quaternion(It it)
:_a(static_cast<T>(*(++it))),
 _b(static_cast<T>(*(++it))),
 _c(static_cast<T>(*(++it))),
 _d(static_cast<T>(*(++it)))
{}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/ZTO86234)