# Cannot deduce template parameter 'N'

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, stdarray, template-argument-deduction

I tried to reduce this to its minimum:

```
#include <array>

template <std::size_t N>
void f(int, std::array<int, N> const & =
       std::array<int, 0>()) {
}


int main() {
    f(10);
}
```

array_test.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
array_test.cpp:10:9: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘N’
     f(10);

Why does this fail? I do not get it: it should be deducible from the default argument. I need a workaround.

Comment: A workaround would be to default N as in `template<std::size_t N = 0>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to give a default value to `N`, not to the array:

```
template <std::size_t N = 0>
void f(int, std::array<int, N> const & =
       std::array<int, N>()) {

}
```

As to why the `N` cannot be deduced from the default value, see [Why can't the compiler deduce the template type from default arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628974/why-cant-the-compiler-deduce-the-template-type-from-default-arguments).