# Data type of default value for template function argument different from instantiating data type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, default-parameters

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 template <typename T>
 void f(T x = std::string{""})
 {
   std::cout << '[' << x << ']' << std::endl;
 }

 int main()
 {
   f(23); // Case 1: Doesn't fail
   f<int>(); // Case 2: Compilation error
   f<int>(23); // Case 3: Doesn't fail
 }
```

Shouldn't the Case 1 and Case 3 also fail, because the function template is instantiated by `int` and the deafult value is of type `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't the Case 1 and Case 3 also fail, because the function
>   template is instantiated by int and the deafult value is of type
>   std::string?

No it shouldn't. See below for why. If you want it to fail then you should define `f()` to be a **regular function** receiving an argument of type `std::string` and **not a *function template*.**

What you have is a case of ***default argument instantiation***, see here in [[temp.inst]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#12):

> If a function template `f` is called in a way that requires a default
>   argument to be used, the dependent names are looked up, the semantics
>   constraints are checked, and **the instantiation [...] is done as if the default argument had been an
>   initializer used in a function template specialization**, [...] This analysis is
>   called *default argument instantiation*. **The instantiated default
>   argument is then used as the argument of `f`**.

When you write:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T x = std::string{""}){...}
```

it means that `""` is the default argument for `x` **only in case the call is made without any arguments**. for example in your *Case 2*.

Your template function is defined to be instatiated just fine for either `int` or various other *types*.

For example here *(Case 1)*:

```
f(23);
```

It is *instatiated implicitly* (by inference base on the argument type) to be `f<int>()`, as `23` is defined in the spec to be an *`int` literal*. The parameter `x` of type `int` receives the *non-default value* of `23` which you have provided at the call site.

And here *(Case 2)*:

```
f<int>();
```

**is exactly where the standard clause above comes into play:** You successfully *instantiate* `f()` but no argument is provided for it, hence *the instantiated default argument is then used as the argument of `f`*. So compilation fails as this *default value* here for parameter `x` is defined to just be `std::string` and no conversion applies from it to type `int`. **It is effectively equivalent to calling `f("")` on a function declared `void f(int x)`**.

And here *(Case 3)*:

```
f<int>(23);
```

Explicit again and this time **you provide the right type of argument at the call site.**

Comment: "It only means that std::string is the default argument for f() in case the call is made without any arguments." You mean `f()` at call site

Comment: @ZeeshanAkhter exactly friend.

Comment: @ZeeshanAkhter I've edited to make it clearer for you. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: for `f()`, you said "it will cause an instantiation of f<std::string>() and the value of x will be an empty string", but type-parameter is not deduced by its default argument, unless you make it default value to type-parameter. FYI https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629009/6367733. So just writing `f()` will fail in this case.

Comment: I ran the code against c++17 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30e259f411b8444d , but still fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178938/discussion-between-skepticalempiricist-and-zeeshan-akhter).

Answer (score 4):

`T x = std::string{""}` is only executed when no arg is given for `x`.

```
f(23)
```

implicit instantiation to `f<int>`. default value for `x` not used because `23` is supplied as an `int` literal.

```
f<int>()
```

now `T` is of type `int` but you are assigning to `x` with a `std::string`

```
f<int>(23)
```

`T` is still `int`, same as case 1

Comment: It seems to be the case, but can you specify the source for this statement.

Comment: [Default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) "Default arguments are used in place of the missing trailing arguments in a function call" 
so the default args are only ever used when x is missing

Comment: What you said below comes into play after default args are worked out. 
"If a function template f is called in a way that requires a default argument to be used"
The OP wants to know why default arguments are not used to force the type of T into a string *always*. The answer is because default arguments only ever come into play when used in place of trailing args in a function call. So what you posted is why the error is caused, but it's not why T is not a string always.

Comment: Nop. What you said implies there's already a function. But this is only a *function template*. So logical precedence is for the instantiation in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Abigail explains why case 1 and 3 do not fail, let me additionally point out that the function template doesn't make that much sense. A function with one parameter that has a default value is expected to be callable like this:

```
void g(std::string = "") { /* ... */ }

g(); // Use default parameter
g("non-default");
```

In contrast, your function template can be called with a given parameter

```
f("non-default");
```

but not without any parameter, because the compiler does not deduce template types from default arguments.

```
f(); // Doesn't compile
```

I would suggest changing the template to

```
 template <typename T = std::string>
 void f(T x = T{})
 {
     // same as before
 }
```

which fixes the `f()` instantiation.