# Question about providing default type for a template

Tags: c++

For example, I wrote the following piece of code:

```
struct default_type {};

template <typename U = default_type> auto func(int x, U u) {
    if constexpr(is_same<U, default_type>::value) {
        return x * 2;
    }
    else {
        return u(x);
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "5 + 3 = " << func(5, [](int x){ return x + 3; }) << endl;
    cout << "5 * 2 = " << func(5) << endl;
}
```

But this gives a compiler error of "no matching function for call to 'func(int)'". What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have provided the default type, but no default value. The function still requires two parameters, and the `default_type` will be overridden by the deduced one, making it useless.

Do this:

```
template <typename U = default_type>
auto func(int x, U u = {}) { ... } // (1)
```

I can't support this by the exact standardese, but in short: `U` is acquired at the *template argument deduction* stage (having no deduction rule - not considering default function arguments, therefore defaulted), which comes before the *overload resolution* stage, at which point the default function arguments are interpreted, already knowing the type of `U`, which makes the list initialization valid.

---

Yes, you could as well write:

```
template <typename U = default_type>
auto func(int x, U u = U()) { ... } // (2)
```

or

```
template <typename U = default_type>
auto func(int x, U u = default_type()) { ... } // (3)
```

with slightly different semantics when explicitly providing the `U` type (which I don't suppose you will):

```
func<not_the_default_type>(5);
```

Here, (1) and (2) are equivalent, but in (3), the construction of `U` happens via constructing a `default_type` temporary, which is then converted to `not_the_default_type`.

---

Lastly, quite the opposite mistake would be to expect `U` to be deduced here:

```
template <typename U>
auto func(int x, U u = default_type()) { ... }
```

which is not the case. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628974/why-cant-the-compiler-deduce-the-template-type-from-default-arguments).

Comment: In a side note, if you give the `default_type` struct an `operator()` implementation, then you don't need the `constexpr` at all: `struct default_type { int operator()(int x) { return x * 2; }}; template <typename U = default_type> auto func(int x, U u = {}) { return u(x); }`