# Default lambda argument in template function

Tags: c++

I want to default a lambda argument in a template function but it fails to compile. What am I missing?

```cpp
template <typename F>
void foo(
  F f = [](){
          std::cout << "Hello!\n";
        }
) {
  f();
}

int main() {
  foo();  // 1. does not compile

  foo([](){ // 2. this is ok
    std::cout << "Hello!\n";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't deduce the template parameter of a function from the default function arguments. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628974) for details on why this restriction is in place.

So you *must* provide a default template parameter yourself. Since you need both the type and the value of the lambda, a simple way to do this would be to write the lambda once, and then use it inside the function template.

```
auto lambda = []() 
              {
                 std::cout << "Bye!\n";
              };
        
template <typename F = decltype(lambda)>  // default parameter
void foo(F f = lambda)                    // default value  
{
  f();
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sadz8K)