# How to pass a lambda to a template paramater

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to define a function `func()`, which returns a `std::string`.

```
template<typename T = std::string, template<typename> typename F = decltype([](const T &t){return t;})>
std::string func(const T &t){
    F f;
    return f(t);
}
```

As you see, what I'm trying to do is to pass a lambda as the template parameter so that I can call the function `func()` like this:

```
func<int, decltype([](int a){return std::to_string(a);})>(2);
```

Also, I set the values by default for the template parameters so that I can call it like this:

```
func<>("abc");
```

However, the code above gave me an error:

```
<source>:39:54: error: expected unqualified-id before 'decltype'
   39 | template<typename T, template<typename> typename F = decltype([](const T &t){return t;})>
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:39:54: error: invalid default argument for a template template parameter
<source>:39:54: error: expected '>' before 'decltype'
```

BTW, the version of my C++ is C++11.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741652/can-we-use-a-lambda-expression-as-the-default-value-for-a-function-argument

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?  IIRC C++20 made this easier.

Comment: If it's non-capturing, make the default a function pointer. Or leave the default out altogether.

Comment: I'm not sure if this counts as a duplicate, but does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66726600/) answer your question?

Comment: @NathanOliver  C++11

Comment: @Yves Okay.  I've added that to the question tags.

Comment: In C++11 you can't have a lambda expression in an unevaluated context (like in the `decltype` specifier). This is possible in C++20 though! see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849059/lambda-expressions-as-class-template-parameters

Comment: You can't default-construct a lambda prior to c++20, and then it's only possible with a non-capturing lambda.

Comment: Why do you want to pass the lambda as a template parameter, instead of just passing it as a function parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11? With a lambda as template parameter?

Given that a lambda (before C++20) can't be used in an unevaluated context (so in a `decltype()`) and can't be default constructed, I don't see a way.

The best I can imagine, in C++11, to reproduce something similar is something as follows

```
template <typename T, typename F = std::function<std::string(T const &)>>
std::string func (T const & t, F f = [](const T &t){return std::string{t};})
 { return f(t); }
```

that you can call with only the first argument

```
func("abc");
```

given that you accept the default lambda (but is saved as a `std::function`).

You can also pass another lambda, if you don't like the default one

```
func(1, [](int const &){ return "one"; });
```

but as a traditional argument, not as template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you can't have a lambda expression in an un-evaluated context, so you'd have to implement this differently I think.

C++20 added this feature, so here's a sample that will compile and run in C++20.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


template<typename T = std::string, typename F = decltype([](const T &t)->std::string{return t;})>
std::string func(const T &t){
    F f;
    return f(t);
}



int main() {
    // convert int to string
    std::cout << func<int, decltype([](int a){return std::to_string(a);})>(2) << std::endl;
    // take float parameter, but just ignore the parameter
    std::cout << func<float, decltype([](float a){return "ignore the param";})>(2.2) << std::endl;
    // default lambda
    std::cout << func("abc") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```